# Migrating angular application into microfrontend application

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, single-spa-angular

I have created the angular application. Now I want to covert this angular application into microfrontend application using single SPA approach, Can anyone plz suggest me what are the steps needs to be follow.
And please suggest the best way to migrate to microfrontend application.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your question, you are not familiar with MicroFrontends architecture and that's a very difficult starting point.
And while this question is likely to be closed, I'd like to answer it anyway. Or, to be more precise, I'll ask you some questions to think about.

1. What do you see as a benefit of migrating to the MicroFrontend architecture?
2. Do you consider yourself familiar with Monolithic applications and can you design them from scratch?
3. Do you expect your MicroFrontends to be reused in different applications?
4. Are your team members well aware of what the MicroFronted is and what are the pros and cons?

If you answered NO at least twice, then don't do it!

I recon this decision is not a requirement but rather an inspiration from some over-hyped article from a mediocre blogs page. That means you'll only end up with a large code-base, which will uses hundreds of lines of code for something achievable in dozens. And what's worst, it'll be more difficult to maintain and hand over.